# ExtJS show "processing download" when downloading a file

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

> I have my ExtJS 4.2.1 Application, where I have a reports section for generating and downloading PDF reports.

Right now in my controller I have this for downloading a file:

```
onPrint: function() {


        Ext.core.DomHelper.append(document.body, {
            tag: 'iframe',
            id: 'downloadIframe',
            frameBorder: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            css: 'display:none;visibility:hidden;height:0px;',
            src: '/api/report/GenerateReport'
        });
}
```

Is working fine, but there are reports that take `5 to 10 seconds to generate`, so the user might `click` several times the `Print` button because he doesn't know that a file it's being generated.

> > How can I show a mask "processing download" or something so I block the UI until the file is downloaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The parent panel that contains the Print button should have the attribute

```
waitMsgTarget: true,
```

and on the button's handler function, before you call onPrint(), add the line:

```
waitMsg: 'Processing download...',
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This wont work when downloading files with Iframe. Actually, Chrome has an issue with IFrame events. It won't never fire onload event.

Comment: Can you share the JS code of that file? I used fpdf library and it worked just fine, if you would like to see what I did, let me know, I will share those files

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I ended with is the following:

A. Call using Ajax a server method that will generate the file but will be stored temporarily on the server. Here I show a wait message

> the name of the file is a Guid.

B. Once the file is created on server I responde the client with a the file name.

C. The client on success response creates an IFrame that it's src property points to the just created file URL.

D. The file is downloaded.